# Breakpoints behaving strangely in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am having two issues with the debugger using visual studio version 9.0.30729.1 using .net 3.1

Issue one - I hit a breakpoint, and F10, F11 do not move me to the next instruction.  If I repeatedly press F10 I will eventually step to the next instruction.   I can place another breakpoint further down in the code and do an F5 to get to the next breakpoint - but I miss the ability to step.

Issue two - I hit my first breakpoint, do an F5 or F10 and the program continues without stopping.

These issues seem to occur semi randomly.  Sometimes they clean themselves up if I shut down visual studio and reboot my computer - but not always.  This does not occur as often in my unit tests as with the GUI application.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a great deal of threads in the program? Could be Thread 1 breaks, you step, thread 2 breaks at the same point that thread 1 just broke at

Comment: I do have a number of threads.  But the thread I am breaking on is the GUI thread.  (IE I am responding to a user action in the Gui).  Not sure how another thread could get into that code

Comment: This has definitely happened to me.  It seems odd to hit step and see yourself jump to a completely different line of code, but that's where another thread jumped to.

Comment: Oh - and I have see this inside of a lock statement - so it feels like something else

Comment: just for the fun of it, try turning on the current thread display in the toolbar. you are probably right that it isn't it, but it isn't that hard to be sure

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the source code hasn't changed after you've started a debugger...

Comment: Source code has not changed.  I can do a full clean / rebuild and no change in behavior

Answer (score 1):

Just for giggles, try turning off just my code.  Uncheck the "just my code ..." option under (Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> General)

JMC can cause odd behavior in scenarios you wouldn't necessarily expect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .pdb files are current, otherwise the source you're debugging and the source you're running might not match.

Comment: date on .pdb files seems to match the last build.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning up your solution directory by deleting (renaming) all files generated by Visual Studio (*.ncb, *.suo, obj/, bin/, and maybe some more).